# How to block bing map pan to coordinate bound?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, bing-maps

I'm using `bing maps components` in C# for WP7 with my custom tiles.
I override `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.TileSource`, all ok, I'm able to use my tiles.

But, because don't have entire world, I want to limit pan only in one city bound?

It's correct to use `MapDragEventArgs` to check and block pan??

```
private void map_MapPan(object sender, MapDragEventArgs e)
{
  Map m = (Map)sender;
  // something...?
}
```

...or I need to override something else?  In that case, what do I need to override?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not worked with Bing Maps on Windows phone 7, so going solely by the documentation, I would do the following:

1. Always initialize the map such that its view bounding rectangle is within your defined tile area.
2. Bind to ViewChangeStart event.  (or ViewChangeOnFrame, you will have to experiment and figure out which to use)
3. Inside handler for ViewChangeStart, check if TargetBoundingRectangle properly falls outside of your tile coverage area.
4. If TargetBoundingRectangle falls outside of your coverage area, figure out a way to cancel the view change or manually set the bounding rectangle back the previous valid state.

Assuming everything works like I expect it to, this should limit the users map navigation to your limited areas and avoid the behavior of the view "Snapping" back to some other place after the user has navigated.

Comment: If you do this on the ViewChangeStart, you will have a bad tilting effect and the user won't understand why this kind of behavior occured. That's why I recommend changing the position of the map using the ViewChangeEnd so you can then pan to match to your bounding box.

Comment: I had assumed that the resulting behavior would be more akin to hitting a solid boundary and not appear jittery when the user navigates to the edges.  Again I haven't actually implemented this so the bad tilting effect you mentioned could very well occur and if that is the case then using ViewChangeEnd is probably better

Answer (score 0):

What you can easily do and would be the best approach is to use the ViewChangeEnd event and set back the map to your coverage area.

See the MSDN reference to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.maps.core.mapcore.viewchangeend(v=vs.92).aspx